# Layoust Issue : Qlistbox in a groupbox auto expands when layout of form is set to vertical

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer, qlayout

I have a Qlistbox inside a QgroupBox whose layout is set to "Layout in a form layout" now the QgroupBox is inside a form whose layout is set to vertical. Actually whenever I set the layout of the form to vertical the QlistBox expands. I have set the size policy of the Listbox to fixed but it still expands. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Try placing a QSpacer next to the list box. If the size policy still gets ignored, try setting a maximum size.